# Play Framework: explain performance

Tags: java, asynchronous, benchmarking, playframework-2.2

I tried to setup a sample Play Framework (version 2.2.2) Java application to test its performace on some simple use case scenarios I had in mind. That's what I did:

**Play controller**

I wrote a basic Application controller to test the performance of a custom library I wanted to use in both sync and async scenarios:

```
public class Application extends Controller {
    public static JsonNode transform(Request request) {
        // this method reads a json from request, applies some transformation and returns a new JsonNode
    }

    public static Result syncTest() {
        JsonNode node = transform(request());
            if(node.has("error")) {
                return badRequest(node);
            } else {
                return ok(node);
            }       
        }

        public static Promise<Result> asyncTest() {
            final Request request = request();
                    Promise<JsonNode> promise = Promise.promise(
                        new Function0<JsonNode>() {
                                public JsonNode apply() {
                            return transform(request);
                                }
                    });

            return promise.map(new Function<JsonNode, Result> () {
            public Result apply(JsonNode node) {
                if(node.has("error")) {
                    return badRequest(node);
                } else {
                    return ok(node);
                }
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

I run this service on virtual machine running on Azure with 2 2.0ghz cores and 3.4gb ram.

**Testing**

I used [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk) from a different machine to perform tests on both sync and async routes. These are the commands and the results I got:

`./wrk -s post.lua  -d30s -c100 -t10 --latency http://my.proxy.net:8080/syncTest`

```
Running 30s test @ 
  10 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    84.98ms   48.13ms 410.73ms   68.95%
    Req/Sec   121.23     18.90   181.00     73.67%
  Latency Distribution
     50%   81.36ms
     75%  112.51ms
     90%  144.44ms
     99%  231.99ms
  36362 requests in 30.03s, 10.99MB read
Requests/sec:   1210.80
Transfer/sec:    374.83KB
```

`./wrk -s post.lua  -d30s -c100 -t10 --latency http://my.proxy.net:8080/asyncTest`

```
Running 30s test @ 
  10 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    82.07ms   36.55ms 257.93ms   70.53%
    Req/Sec   122.44     15.39   161.00     73.24%
  Latency Distribution
     50%   80.26ms
     75%  102.37ms
     90%  127.14ms
     99%  187.17ms
  36668 requests in 30.02s, 11.09MB read
Requests/sec:   1221.62
Transfer/sec:    378.18KB
```

`./wrk -s post.lua  -d30s -c1000 -t10 --latency http://my.proxy.net:8080/syncTest`

```
Running 30s test @ 
  10 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   842.98ms  617.40ms   4.18s    59.56%
    Req/Sec   118.02     16.82   174.00     77.50%
  Latency Distribution
     50%  837.67ms
     75%    1.14s 
     90%    1.71s 
     99%    2.51s 
  35326 requests in 30.01s, 10.68MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 27, write 0, timeout 181
Requests/sec:   1176.97
Transfer/sec:    364.35KB
```

`./wrk -s post.lua  -d30s -c1000 -t10 --latency http://my.proxy.net:8080/asyncTest`

```
Running 30s test @ 
  10 threads and 1000 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     5.98s     4.53s   17.97s    72.66%
    Req/Sec    21.32     10.45    37.00     59.74%
  Latency Distribution
     50%    4.86s 
     75%    8.30s 
     90%   12.89s 
     99%   17.10s 
  6361 requests in 30.08s, 1.92MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 0, write 0, timeout 8410
Requests/sec:    211.47
Transfer/sec:     65.46KB
```

During all tests, both cpus of the server's machine were working 100%. Later, I repeated this experiments but modified the Promises I was creating to run on a different execution context than the default. In this case both sync and async methods performed in a very similar way.

**Questions**

1. Why is it that, when using 10 threads with 100 connections, both methods have similar latency and request per seconds.
2. Why is it that, with 1000 connections, async method seems to have worst performance that async or, in case of a separate execution context, similar performance to sync methods?

Is it related to the transform method not being really cpu intensive, because I did the async implementation wrong or because I have completely misunderstood how this thing is supposed to work?

Thanks in advance!